# Is it possible to force Grand Theft Auto 1 to run at 1080 resolution?

Tags: grand-theft-auto

I've been searching Google but it only gives answers for GTA4 and since I've bought the GTA Pack on Steam, I'd like to play the older games but in a better resolution than 800x600. Is there any way to do this? Maybe a program that forces them to this resolution or perhaps an ini change?

Comment: GTA1 is a DOS game, as far as I remember - you're probably lucky it even runs on modern hardware. As for changing the resolution, press F11 in game to cycle through the supported resolutions that the game will run at.

Comment: It works fine, something bought from Steam should do! But like I said I'd like to record with it. I'll give the F11 thing a go though, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Get a PS1/PS2 emulator and GTA1, then set emulator resolution to 1080p and run it. You can even scale textures, etc.

I guess there's no way to achieve that with the Steam version.

Comment: He bought it on Steam, so unless you want to mention how to use an emulator with that version, this answer isn't very helpful.

Comment: Still, it's the only way to play it on 1080p and that's what he asked for. But thanks for the downvote.

Comment: @MBraedley Just because the answer doesn't apply to the one who asked the question, it might still be useful for someone else with the same question.

Comment: @3ventic - An answer should answer the question before it start to answer all other questions that might exist.

Comment: @Ramhound While it might not apply for Simon's case, it still *answers the question*.

Answer (score 1):

A game needs to internally support a resolution in order to produce graphics at that resolution—there's no way to force a resolution that's unsupported without recoding parts of the graphics engine itself. This *can* be done with a lot of skill and code injection, but my searches turn up nothing: it doesn't look like anyone has done a graphics engine enhancer for GTA1.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Never mind then I'll just have to settle with a smaller resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ThirteenAG's widescreen fix](https://thirteenag.github.io/wfp#gta1) (the screenshots are captured in 1,920 × 1,080).